# To make clone of row and append into table in jquery having kendo combobox

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have created a table in view page of mvc.

On the click of textbox, I created a clone of row with the control it is working as expected. But the problem that I am facing with kendo combobox it is not working as expected.

Below is the jquery code:

```
    function Addrows(){   
     var row = $("#tblVisitFrequencies tr").last().clone();
                var oldId = Number(row.attr('id').slice(-1));
                var id = 100 + oldId;

                alert(modelResource);
                row.attr('id', 'allergyrow_' + id );

                row.find('#AllergyNameMedsTreatments_' + oldId).attr('id', 'AllergyNameMedsTreatments_' + id);
                row.find('#AllergyNameMedsTreatments_' + id).attr('name', 'AllergyNameMedsTreatments_' + id); 


     $('#tblVisitFrequencies').append(row);
   }
```

From the above code we are creating the clone of row. Please provide some help.

Comment: Implmentation of kendo combobox     
    @(Html.Kendo().ComboBox()
          .Name("customers")
          .DataTextField("ContactName")
          .DataValueField("CustomerID")
          .MinLength(3)
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%;" }))

Answer (score 0):

Try this will it work:

```
function Addrows(){   
     var row = $("#tblVisitFrequencies tr").last().clone();
                var oldId = Number(row.attr('id').slice(-1));
                var id = 100 + oldId;

                alert(modelResource);
                row.attr('id', 'allergyrow_' + id );

                row.find('#AllergyNameMedsTreatments_' + oldId).attr('id', 'AllergyNameMedsTreatments_' + id);
                row.find('#AllergyNameMedsTreatments_' + id).attr('name', 'AllergyNameMedsTreatments_' + id); 
    // THIS LINE, CHANGE THE VALUE INSIDE OF FIND
     $(row).find("CLASS_OR_ID_SELECTION_OF_INPUT").kendoComboBox();
     $('#tblVisitFrequencies').append(row);
   }
```

Comment: I used this in our application but getting error browser console "kendo combobox is not a function".  Thanks in advance    Its urgent please help me